# Primefaces 6.1 p:inputTextarea unexpand the text box

Tags: primefaces

[image]How can disable the user is able to expand the text box

```
    <p:inputTextarea title="Json English" id="jsonEditorEn" autoResize="false" scrollHeight="120" rows="15" 
style="font-size:15px" value="#{dynamicLayoutView.selectedDynamicLayout.dataEn}"> </p:inputTextarea>
```

Comment: Please try to **always** add version information

Comment: i will ,Thanks !

Comment: Then please do ;-) You can edit your question

Comment: Unless it works with 6.0 and not 6.1 and unknown in 6.2, you should not add version info (or tags) to the title but in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
styleClass="unresizable"
```

Comment: that's work when i add .unresizable {
    resize: none;
}

Comment: @Funkjelly. Finding duplicates in Stackoverflow and closing//flagging the question as such is a good thing in Stackoverflow. It prevents fragmentation. Cheers

Comment: @Kukeltje fully agree. My bad

Comment: No problem, always appreciate the effort to help... Cheers... (sometimes answer help to find the duplicates  ;-)